# Retain default behavior when AuthorizedPrincipalsFile set

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, certificates

I'm using certificate-based authentication for SSH. On one of my servers, I set `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile` to `.ssh/authorized_principals` in order to allow me to log into another user with my certificate.

However, after doing so, I was unable to use my certificate to log into my own account, as I had not created my own `~/.ssh/authorized_principals`, not expecting setting this option to disable the default behavior of checking the username against the supplied principals.

Is there a way to retain the default username-matching behavior and support an authorized_principals file in addition without using `AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand` as a workaround?